# Create a Cloud Function that is sensitive to the deployment of a new version in Firebase Hosting?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am trying to implement a function that will be triggered once a new version has been released—in other words, once my Firebase deployment finishes deploying all the changes. Does Firebase support such a possibility? I want to enable live updates for my app once I release a new version.

```js
// on new version release
exports.onHostingRelease = functions
  .runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 540, memory: '2GB' })
  .hosting.site('your-site-name')
  .onRelease((versionMetadata) => {
    // versionMetadata is an object that contains information about the new version
    console.log('New version deployed:', versionMetadata.versionString);

    // You can perform any actions you need here, such as sending a notification
    // or updating a database record

    return null;
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All supported Firebase triggers are listed and described under the "Trigger background functions" section of the document in the left navigation you see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions).  As of this writing, there are no triggers for Firebase Hosting.

Feel free to send feedback to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) with your feature request.

Comment: feed back sent.